# Laravel Eloquent find posts that has all the given tags

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

Consider 3 tables as below

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'post_tags', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
    }

}
```

`posts` table

```
|id | title   |
+---+---------+
|1  |  post1  |
|2  |  post2  |
|3  |  post3  |
|4  |  post4  |
```

`tags` table

```
|id |  value  |
+---+---------+
|1  |  tag01  |
|2  |  tag02  |
|3  |  tag03  |
|4  |  tag04  |
```

`post_tags` table

```
|  post_id | tag_id  |
+----------+---------+
|     1    |    1    |
|     2    |    3    |
|     2    |    4    |
|     3    |    1    |
|     4    |    1    |
|     4    |    4    |
```

The only post that has both `tag01` and `tag04` is post with `id = 4`

But when I get `posts` with this code

```
Post::whereHas('tags', function($q) {
  $q->whereIn('tag_id', [1, 4]);
}
```

I get all the posts that has `tag01` or `tag04`.

I want to get `Post`s where have both `tag01` and `tag02` in its `tags` relation.

How can I achieve this result using `Eloquent` or if it's not possible using `QueryBuilder`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use  multiple where condition

```
 Post::whereHas('tags', function($q) {
       $q->where('tag_id', 1);
   
    })->whereHas('tags', function($q) {
       $q->where('tag_id', 4);
   
    })->get();
```

if ids are dynamic then

```
$id=[1,4];
    Post::where(function($query)use($id){
        foreach ($id as $value){
            $query->whereHas('tags',function ($query)use($value){

                $query->where('tag_id',$value);


            });
        }


    })->get();
```

Comment: The updated answer worked as expected, thank you.

Comment: @HadiSharghi .lagbox  answer also works well and its simple

Answer (score 3):

The `whereHas` method takes more arguments and one of them is a count:

```
Post::whereHas('tags', fn ($q) => $q->whereIn('tag_id', $tags), '=', count($tags))->get();
```

If you are looking for `[1, 4]` what this is saying is find me all Posts that have tags `1` or `4` but then only pick the ones that have exactly 2 of these (the count), which means find all Posts that have all these tags.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) `whereHas`

Comment: its simple and clean.

Comment: @HadiSharghi I added more of a description for you

Comment: Very clever! Thanks for clarification